# Sharing Audio Streams In Firefox when using Gksudo

Tags: pulseaudio, streaming, gksudo

My admin user has proprietary information, banking info and internet password database on it's account. In order to use apps while online, prevent apps from contacting the internet silently, bring up internet passwords safely, I do all that with a firewalled account.

Yet while doing all the above, in the same account, I bring up Firefox to surf the internet.  I bring up Firefox as a non-admin user using gksudo.  *For those of you who don't know gksudo, this all looks like it is being done seemlessly on one desktop, while you can have several users running apps for you!*

This is the command:  gksudo -u internet /usr/bin/firefox &

Here is the problem:  [padevchooser has been refused to be fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/padevchooser/+bug/851695), which allowed this audio sharing to happen with a simple check of a box.  I cannot hear the audio in Firefox while admin runs Firefox as another user.

Is there some other way I can set things up manually so the sound is always played when user:  internet plays videos in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

This may be one of the top five wrong ways to fix audio according to this, but it worked.

http://voices.canonical.com/david.henningsson/2012/07/13/top-five-wrong-ways-to-fix-your-audio/

Adding the user who will be running the app to the audio group.  Since the user in my example is called internet, this commands works:

```
 usermod -a -G audio internet
```

Comment: This solution isn't working for me on 16.04 LTS. Is anything changed recently?